# export excel from mysql data to excel file with large number in php

Tags: php, excel, codeigniter, export

**Use This Code Working Fine :**
sometime while you export excel file, you get this problem .
**example : 8001114051777785 but transforms into 8,00111E+15**

```
public function export_excel(){
        header("Content-Type: application/xls");
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="order_code_'.date('d_m_Y_His').'.xls"');
        $header=array('Order ID', 'Email','Create Time');
        $this->db->select('orders_id,  customer_email, create_time');
        $this->db->from('table');
         $this->db->order_by('orders_id', 'ASC');
        $this->db->limit(100);
        $referrerdata = $this->db->get()->result();
        $sep = "\t"; //tabbed character
        foreach ($header as $h){
            echo trim($h) . "\t";
        }
        print("\n");
        foreach($referrerdata as $data){
            $schema_insert = " ";
            $schema_insert .=isset($data->orders_id) ? " ' ".(string)$data->orders_id.$sep:"NULL".$sep;
            $schema_insert .=isset($data->customer_email) ? $data->customer_email.$sep:"NULL".$sep;
            $schema_insert .=isset($data->create_time) ? $data->create_time.$sep:"NULL".$sep;
            $schema_insert = str_replace($sep."$", "", $schema_insert);
            $schema_insert = preg_replace("/\r\n|\n\r|\n|\r/", " ", $schema_insert);
            $schema_insert .= "\t";
            print(trim($schema_insert));
            print "\n";

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Excel automatically formats large numbers into Scientific Notation, to force Excel to use Text formatting, add an apostrophe before the ID like this `'8001114051777785`

Comment: yes i have also used this " ' " in the function. this is complete code i have shared